# How to map using useState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have an input field where I would like to enter a number; this number then should be stored in the specified key "mktratedelta" in the state.

I am doing this with mapping. For some reason, I am not able to type in the input field. Is this the right approach and how to fix this issue?

```js
const [marketEstimateDataBCAssets, setmarketEstimateData] = useState([
    {
      name: "Lombard",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.03,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Other Secured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.033,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Unsecured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.0333,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    }
  ]);

{Object.keys(marketEstimateDataBCAssets).map(function(key) {
        return (
          <Segment>
            <div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].name}</div>
            <div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].prevgroupinputrate}</div>
            <div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].currgroupinputrate}</div>
            <input
              value={marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].mktratedelta}
              onChange={e =>
                (marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].mktratedelta = e.target.value)
              }
            />
            <div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].mktrateestimate}</div>
          </Segment>
        );
```

Comment: Please paste the complete component code

Comment: If you want to change `marketEstimateDataBCAssets` you'll need to call `setmarketEstimateData` instead of mutating it.

Comment: Also `marketEstimateDataBCAssets` is an array not an object. `Object.keys(marketEstimateDataBCAssets)` should not work as desired. You will get an array `["0", "1"]` of this kind

Comment: @GangadharGandi I am calling setmarketEstimateData but i am still not able to enter in the input field

Comment: @Julian what should i do instead ?

Comment: @CliveCharles use map straight. As in `marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(asset => (<div>{asset.name}</div>))`

Comment: You can just map over your array directly, no need for Object.keys. Also, for a state object this size I would suggest looking into useReducer. Also, create another function below your hook and call this from the DOM element, then, inside said function perform and data structure manipulation logic you want to pass to the state Hook. Keep functions small and testable and only update sections of your state in an Immutable way to prevent side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to split up the logic into two components and render out a list of assets

```js
function myAwesomeComponent() {
  const [marketData, setMarketData] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Lombard',
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.03,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Other Secured',
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.033,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Unsecured',
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.0333,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04,
    },
  ]);

  const onChange = (asset) => (event) => {
    setMarketData((oldMarketData) => {
      const index = oldMarketData.indexOf(asset);
      const oldAsset = oldMarketData[index];
      const newMarketData = [...oldMarketData];
      newMarketData[index] = {
        ...oldAsset,
        mktratedelta: event.target.value,
      };
      return newMarketData;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {marketData.map((asset) => (
        <Asset asset={asset} onChange={onChange} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

const Asset = ({ asset, onChange }) => (
  <Segment key={asset.id}>
    <div> {asset.name}</div>
    <div> {asset.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
    <div> {asset.currgroupinputrate}</div>
    <input value={asset.mktratedelta} onChange={onChange(asset)} />
    <div> {asset.mktrateestimate}</div>
  </Segment>
);
```

If you have influence on the property names from the marketData array, then you should consider using camelCase, so

```js
{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Lombard',
  prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
  currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
  mktratedelta: 0.03,
  mktrateestimate: 0.04,
}
```

becomes

```js
{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Lombard',
  prevGroupInputrate: 0.01,
  currGroupInputrate: 0.02,
  mktRateDelta: 0.03,
  mktRateEstimate: 0.04,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly changing the `state`. Don't do this. Try something like this:

```
 return (
           <>
      {marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, key) => (
        <div>
          <div> {item.name}</div>
          <div> {item.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
          <div> {item.currgroupinputrate}</div>
          <input
            value={item.mktratedelta}
            onChange={e => {
              const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
                if (el.name === item.name) {
                  return { ...el, mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value) };
                }
                return el;
              });
              console.log(newArr);

              return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
            }}
          />
          <div> {item.mktrateestimate}</div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>

        );
```

here is a quick [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58716819-ru31i). thanks to @Titus for pointing out the issue.

Comment: This will add a new value to the `marketEstimateDataBCAssets` array, you should use something like `.map(..)` instead of spreading.

Comment: @blueseal the value in "<div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].mktrateestimate}</div>" is not changing and in the console i get the following error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined" whenever I enter something in the input field

Comment: @CliveCharles I forgot to convert string to float `parseFloat(e.target.value)`. I updated the code. https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58716819-ru31i. I think  You want to change `input` `mktratedelta` not `mktrateestimate`

Comment: First of all thank you, what I am trying to do is to display the addition of  "currgroupinputrate" and "mktratedelta" in "mktrateestimate" I wanted to start small so i tried to enter something in "mktratedelta" input field then this input shoulb be diplayed in mktrateestimate but i wasnt able to

Comment: You can create another question on SO and I will answer that. I think this question is different than what you are currently facing. :)

Comment: how will you find the question ?

Comment: okay cool, this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736130/how-to-add-2-keys-from-usestate-using-mapping-react

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code.
1. you can't do `Object.keys` on  Arrays (`marketEstimateDataBCAssets` is an array in your code);

2. you can't Directly assign values to the state object.

you can solve the first issue by simply removing `Object.keys`;

for the second issue just create a function pass the array key value with the input value. In the function create an array with and update the value of the indexed object then simply pass the new array data to `setmarketEstimateData`

so the code will be:

```
const [marketEstimateDataBCAssets, setmarketEstimateData] = useState([
  {
    name: "Lombard",
    prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
    currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
    mktratedelta: 0.03,
    mktrateestimate: 0.04
  },
  {
    name: "Other Secured",
    prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
    currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
    mktratedelta: 0.033,
    mktrateestimate: 0.04
  },
  {
    name: "Unsecured",
    prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
    currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
    mktratedelta: 0.0333,
    mktrateestimate: 0.04
  }
]);

function updateValue(e, key) {
  let data =  setmarketEstimateData;
  data[key].mktratedelta = e.target.value;
  marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(data);
}

{marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(function(item,key) {
  return (
    <Segment>
      <div> {item.name}</div>
      <div> {item.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
      <div> {item.currgroupinputrate}</div>
      <input
        value={item.mktratedelta}
        onChange={e => updateValue(e, updateValue(e, key))}
      />
      <div> {item.mktrateestimate}</div>
    </Segment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this but here I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: thanks for the answer but this code gives me "Cannot set property 'mktratedelta' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const Component = () => {

  const [marketEstimateDataBCAssets, setmarketEstimateData] = useState([
    {
      name: "Lombard",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.03,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Other Secured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.033,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Unsecured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.0333,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    }
  ]);

  const preSetEstimateData = (value, itemId) => {

    const item = marketEstimateDataBCAssets[itemId];
    const newItem = {
      ...item,
      mktrateestimate: value,
    }

    setmarketEstimateData([
      ...marketEstimateDataBCAssets.slice(0, itemId),
      newItem,
      ...marketEstimateDataBCAssets.slice(itemId)
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {
        marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, id) => {
          return (
            <Segment>
              <div> {item.name}</div>
              <div> {item.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
              <div> {item.currgroupinputrate}</div>
              <input
                value={item.mktratedelta}
                onChange={e => preSetEstimateData(e.target.value, id)}
              />
              <div> {item.mktrateestimate}</div>
            </Segment>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component;
```