# How to add 2 keys from useState using mapping React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

what I am trying to do is to display the addition of "currgroupinputrate" and "mktratedelta" in "mktrateestimate" I wanted to start small so I tried to enter something in "mktratedelta" input field ,this input should be then displayed in mktrateestimate but its not displaying the input in mktratedelta. How to fix this and what would be the right approach ?

````
const [marketEstimateDataBCAssets, setmarketEstimateData] = useState([
    {
      name: "Lombard",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.03,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Other Secured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.033,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    },
    {
      name: "Unsecured",
      prevgroupinputrate: 0.01,
      currgroupinputrate: 0.02,
      mktratedelta: 0.0333,
      mktrateestimate: 0.04
    }
  ]);


  return (
      {marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <Segment>
            <div> {item.name}</div>
            <div> {item.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
            <div> {item.currgroupinputrate}</div>
            <input
              value={item.mktratedelta}
              onChange={e => {
                const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
                  if (el.name === item.name) {
                    return { ...el, mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value) };
                  }
                  return el;
                });
                console.log(newArr);

                return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
              }}
            />
            <div> {marketEstimateDataBCAssets[key].mktrateestimate}</div>
          </Segment>
        );
      })} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58736130-lpi0o). It just the start you can carry on yourself from there. You should find a way to manage your controlled `input`. For more read [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:~:text=In%20a%20controlled%20component%2C%20form,form%20values%20from%20the%20DOM.) and [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in react. check out [parseFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4435190/5124488) in javascript.

```
return (
    <>
      {marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map((item, key) => (
        <div key={item.name}>
          {/* let's name is unique */}
          <div> {item.name}</div>
          <div> {item.prevgroupinputrate}</div>
          <div> {item.currgroupinputrate}</div>
          <input
            value={item.mktratedelta}
            onChange={e => {
              const newArr = marketEstimateDataBCAssets.map(el => {
                if (el.name === item.name) {
                  return {
                    ...el,
                    mktratedelta: parseFloat(e.target.value),
                    mktrateestimate: (
                      parseFloat(e.target.value) + item.currgroupinputrate
                    ).toFixed(4)
                  };
                }
                return el;
              });
              console.log(newArr);

              return setmarketEstimateData([...newArr]);
            }}
          />
          <div> {item.mktrateestimate}</div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: thanks for the code.... could you also show me how I can put this function outside the main "return" and then call the it from "onChange" so I can reuse the function